# IndexError out of range on Python

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, argv, sys

I have a python code to insert data into my database. Here is the line:
`query = 'insert into 1_recipe values({0})'`. I used `{0}` to pass all data from my CSV file. It works perfectly before I use `sys.argv` in my code. Here is the new code :

```
import sys

nomor = sys.argv[1]

.....
    query = "insert into {idnumber}_recipe values ({0})".format(idnumber = nomor)
    query = query.format(','.join(['%s'] * len(data)))
.....
```

When I run this code, always back with this error :

```
'query = "insert into {idnumber}_recipe values ({0})".format(idnumber = nomor)
IndexError: Replacement index 0 out of range for positional args tuple'
```

How to fix it? Thanks.

**Update:**
I already found the answer. Thank you

Comment: Please review [How to use variables in an SQL statement in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902408/how-to-use-variables-in-sql-statement-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

You are only passing one argument to the `format()` function:

```
.format(idnumber = nomor)
```

The format function doesn't have a value to give to the `({0})` part of the formatted string.
Either give another value or change it so it will use `idnumber` as well

Answer (score 0):

You can look at query development for formatting [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html).

e.g.:

```
insert_stmt = (
  "INSERT INTO employees (emp_no, first_name, last_name, hire_date) "
  "VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)"
)
data = (2, 'Jane', 'Doe', datetime.date(2012, 3, 23))
cursor.execute(insert_stmt, data)
```

Your code can be rewritten something like this using better formatting:

```
import sys

nomor = sys.argv[1]

data_str_value = ','.join(['%s'] * len(data))
.....
    query = "insert into {idnumber}_recipe values ({values})".format(idnumber = nomor, values = data_str_value)
.....
```

Note: This code is showing only better formatting as per the example given. This query may or may not run as expected due to incorrect syntax.